# jQuery Datatables search textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Why will my search textbox not initialize as empty?  I have tried:

```
table.state.clear();
```

and I have tried:

```
"bStateSave": false, // save datatable state(pagination, sort, etc) in cookie.
```

After I use the filter, redirect to another View, create a new search, then come back to my search results the textbox always has the last string I used for a filter.

I'm using MVC5 as my framework.

[image]

[image]

```
var initTable4 = function () {

    var table = $('#sample_4');
    table.dataTable({

        "language": {
            "aria": {
                "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
            },
            "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
            "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
            "infoEmpty": "No records found",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total records)",
            "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_",
            "search": "Search:",
            "zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
            "paginate": {
                "previous":"Prev",
                "next": "Next",
                "last": "Last",
                "first": "First"
            }
        },            

        "bStateSave": false, // save datatable state(pagination, sort, etc) in cookie.

        "lengthMenu": [
            [6, 15, 20, -1],
            [6, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
        ],
        // set the initial value
        "pageLength": 6,
        "columnDefs": [{  // set default column settings
            'orderable': false,
            'targets': [0]
        }, {
            "searchable": false,
            "targets": [0]
        }],
        "order": [
            [1, "asc"]
        ] // set first column as a default sort by asc
    });

    var tableWrapper = jQuery('#sample_4_wrapper');

    table.find('.group-checkable').change(function () {
        var set = jQuery(this).attr("data-set");
        var checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");
        jQuery(set).each(function () {
            if (checked) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `table.search('').draw()` would clear out the value of specifically the search box, but would still keep any existing column searchers you may have.

I implemented it for a [x] clear box on the search field as follows.

```
$(document).on('input', '.clearable',
function () {
    $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
}).on('mousemove', '.x', function (e) {

    $(this)[tog(
    this.offsetWidth - 18 < e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
}).on('click', '.onX', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
    table.search('').draw();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have noticed table.search('').draw() mentioned on other SOF questions and have tried it.  Maybe I'm not using the empty string in the correct location in the code.

Comment: As a test have you tried just clearing the textbox manually with jQuery to see if it fires the search clear function? I think it does

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#sample_4').dataTable({ 
    responsive : true,
    search : {
               search : '' //set search field as empty
             }
})
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation.